# Generate Alpha numeric unique id for each row in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a VBA code which would do the following task

Whenever there is an entry in the Name column the VBA will automatically generate id's for each row.

```
id       Name
NL-1     abc
NL-2     fljf
NL-3     fdgfd
NL-4     dsfsd
NL-5     dsfdsf
```

I am using the following VBA script and it works fine when it is just numbers.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim maxNumber, x As Long
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Cells(Target.Row, 1) > 0 Then Exit Sub
    maxNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A"))
    Target.Offset(0, -1) = maxNumber + 1
End If
End Sub
```

The output of above code

```
id  Name
1   abc
2   ada
3   skfn
```

But when I try to introduce "NL=" in the code thats where I am facing problems.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim maxNumber, x As Long
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Cells(Target.Row, 1) > 0 Then Exit Sub
    maxNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A"))
    Target.Offset(0, -1) = "NL-" & maxNumber + 1
End If
End Sub
```

The output of this code is

```
id     Name
NL-1   abc
NL-1   ada
NL-1   skfn
```

Please let me know if someone can figure this out. This would be a huge help.
Thanks.

Comment: By introducing "NL-", column A contains strings and you cannot calculate the maximum of strings. So maybe add a column which stores just the number?

Comment: @SJR yes that could be done but it would be just nice to have the "NL-" part in the same column based on my requirement as I want to push this data into a database and connect it to tableau for further visualizations!

Comment: Is `="NL-"&row(A1)` not an option? Make your data a table with Ctrl+T and the formula will autopopulate?

Comment: Yes well you can do that, you just have to concatenate it with that stored number, or just the number of rows of data if your sequence is 1,2,3 etc with no blanks or inconsistencies (i.e. if you are row 3 you know your max value will be 3).

Comment: Or if the IDs are guaranteed to start at `NL-1` and never skip a subsequent integer, then just use COUNTIF with a wildcard on that column.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, the ="NL-"&A1 works perfectly for me. But I have to drag down the cells to apply the formula to each row. Is there a way to autopopulate  the formula in the next column where it will generate this combination whenever there is an entry in the name column ?

Comment: Make your data a table with Ctrl+T

Comment: @SJR, yes I did the same thing and it works. Thankyou!

Comment: @BigBen Perfect! Thank you. Also , one of the other problem I am facing with the code is when I delete a row the id does not decrease. For example, if I delete id = 2 then the next row does not decrease its value to 2 like from id = 3 to id =2. Should I ask a new question for this?

Comment: Hmm maybe you want `="NL-"&ROW()-1` as your formula.

Comment: @BigBen thank you! Got what I was looking for!